# Checking if a set of strings exist in a column with a custom function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Fellow contributors,

I would like to check if a set of specific key words exists on a grouped pandas DataFrame. The words I would like to check are `start`, `pending` and either `finished` or `almost_finished`. I would like to define a custom function for this and `apply` it to pandas `groupby` as defining a function to apply on columns is a bit not clear for me comparing to rowwise operations where we address every row with (row[colname]).
In this example if the sequence of the desired words exist I would like the last value in column `number` for each `ID` to be copied in a new column and it doesn't matter if other values before that are empty strings. Here is a reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [1100, 1100, 1100, 1200, 1200, 1200, 1300, 1300],
                  'number' : ['Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No'],
                  'status' : ['start', 'pending', 'finished', 'start', 'pending', 'partially_finished', 'start', 'pending']})
```

In this case the last group of `ID == 1300` has no return value.
Basically I am asking this question to learn the best approach for these kinda problem where you need to check some values in a column, since I am coming from R I need to familiarize myself with the way I would do the same thing in Python. I would also appreciate any better solution you may suggest.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate with `set` and use `intersection` to check.

But first, I would map `partially_finished` or `almost_finished` to `finished`, if these should be treated equally.

```py
df['status'] = df.status.replace('partially_finished|almost_finished', 'finished', regex=True)
```

Next, aggregate `number` to last value and `status` to `set`, then I use `intersect` to check if all values are existing in `status`.

```py
checkcriteria = {'start', 'pending', 'finished'}
df = df.groupby('ID').agg({'number': 'last', 'status': set})
df['check'] = df.status.transform(lambda x: len(x.intersection(checkcriteria)) == 3)
```

This should give a result,

```
     number                      status  check
ID
1100     No  {start, pending, finished}   True
1200     No  {start, pending, finished}   True
1300     No            {start, pending}  False
```

You can either filter by `check` or `mask` and remove the value for `number`.

```py
# This will only return ID == 1100, 1200
df[df.check]

# OR mask to remove the number value for when check == False
df.loc[~df.check, 'number'] = None
```

Comment: Quite interesting that a transform + lambda is actually faster than other options

Comment: not sure but maybe because `transform` is applied to already aggregated dataframe (~1/3 of original in size)?

Comment: Indeed, that would justify the speedup over the groupby-apply

Comment: Thank you very much Emma for your solution, it looks interesting indeed.

Answer (score 1):

[df.groupby.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) is probably what you're looking for. You can apply a function to each group and return either a single value, series, or dataframe. The result will be aggregated together.

e.g. the following function

```py
def return_last_num(df):
    if df.status.str.contains('start').any() & df.status.str.contains('pending').any() \
        & (df.status.str.contains('finished').any() | df.status.str.contains('partically_finished').any()):
        df['last_number'] = df.number.values[-1]
    else:
        df['last_number'] = str()
    return df
```

When applied: `df.groupby('ID').apply(return_last_num)`.

Returns:

```
     ID number              status last_number
0  1100    Yes               start          No
1  1100     No             pending          No
2  1100     No            finished          No
3  1200    Yes               start          No
4  1200     No             pending          No
5  1200     No  partially_finished          No
6  1300    Yes               start            
7  1300     No             pending
```

**Alternatively: returning a single value**

```py
def return_last_num(df):
    if df.status.str.contains('start').any() & df.status.str.contains('pending').any() \
        & (df.status.str.contains('finished').any() | df.status.str.contains('partically_finished').any()):
        return df.number.values[-1]
    else:
        return str()
```

When applied: `df.groupby('ID').apply(return_last_num)`.

Returns just the last 'number' value per ID if the sequence condition was matched:

```
ID
1100    No
1200    No
1300
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, this was in my mind at first and it was interesting to know that without `groupby` I could not apply a custom function on columns of a pandas data frame.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR you absolutely can check out DataFrame.apply / applymap / transform.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking on a vectorized approach.

First, if `finished` and `almost finished` have the same effect, I would "merge" them, and would make them a unique number easy to check:

```
>>> df['status2'] = df['status'].map({'finished':1,'partially_finished':1,'pending':10,'start':100})
>>> df
     ID number              status  status2
0  1100    Yes               start      100
1  1100     No             pending       10
2  1100     No            finished        1
3  1200    Yes               start      100
4  1200     No             pending       10
5  1200     No  partially_finished        1
6  1300    Yes               start      100
7  1300     No             pending       10
```

That allows me to "extract" the desired status (100+10+1):

```
idstatus=df.groupby('ID', sort=False).sum('status2')==111
      status2
ID
1100     True
1200     True
1300    False
```

And the actual number values: if you don't need to match *all* words only this line would be enough.

```
valuenumber=df.query('status2==1').set_index('ID')
     number              status  status2
ID
1100     No            finished        1
1200     No  partially_finished        1
```

And finally merge:

```
idstatus.merge(valuenumber, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
>>> idstatus.merge(valuenumber, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
      status2_x number              status  status2_y
ID
1100       True     No            finished        1.0
1200       True     No  partially_finished        1.0
1300      False    NaN                 NaN        NaN
```

it is possible to merge less entries:

```
>>> idstatus.merge(valuenumber[['number','status']], left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
      status2 number              status
ID
1100     True     No            finished
1200     True     No  partially_finished
1300    False    NaN                 NaN
>>>
```

**Edit:**
If you only want to have the outputs of the finished ones, you can get it also with this oneliner:

```
>>> valuenumber.loc[idstatus[idstatus.status2].index][['number','status']]
     number              status
ID
1100     No            finished
1200     No  partially_finished
>>>
```

**Edit2: Just benchmarked** Interestingly, the intersect solution is *faster*, at least for the sample data:

- groubpy-apply: 2.86ms
- aggregate & merge: 3.90ms
- vector & loc: 3.96ms
- **set-intersect: 2.4ms albeit using *lambda***

**Edit3:** I was too dense yesterday. Using Emma's idea of "two operations in one groupby", and assuming that items are status is ordered:

```
df2['status'] = df2.status.map({'finished':1,'partially_finished':1,'pending':10,'start':100})
x = df2.groupby('ID').agg({'number': 'last', 'status': 'sum'})
x[x.status==111]
```

At 2.1ms, it is slightly faster than versions with apply / lambda

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, the fact that you first mapped values to categories and then use the sum is indeed a clever idea. Is it possible to filter pandas groupby without the loss of any column? Because only the grouped variable and the aggregated ones remain.

Comment: In general it depends on the operation carried out.  "Agg" offers maximum flexibility, allowing you to perform aggregation with different functions on different columns. There are other functions like "sum" that are applied to all columns, for instance as groupby.sum

Comment: Yes you are right, haven't thought about it that way. I should aggregate others as well too. But yes I worked with `agg` and it looks interesting in particular when you pass a dictionary of column name function name.